# Как сделать генерацию объектов в unity2d

Tags: unity3d

Посмотрел несколько гайдов на yotube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHm_FYK98VQ
Второй который смотрел он точноо такой же

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generation : MonoBehaviour
{
   public GameObject[] objects;
   

void Start()
{
    int rand = Random.Range(0, objects.Length);
    Instantiate(objects[rand], transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

}

Расставил точки спавна как в видео, но когда нажимаю пуск(play) То в самой игре их нет а на сцене они респавняться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А должно быть как? Вроде бы у вас остров нормально заспавнился

Comment: Как понять как должно быть... 
Я имел виду спавн РЕСУРСОВ а не ландшафта. 

И как вы видите на сцене слева появился куст а в самой игре справа его нет

Comment: Может нужно увеличить параметр `OrderInLayer` компонента `SpriteRenderer`? Сделать это прямо в префабе куста

Comment: Я решил проблему.
Просто я немного туповат и создавал респавн на сцене, а сейчас респавн в tilemap острова